# Macro NO_ERROR conflict

Tags: c++, macros

In `winerror.h`:

```
...
#define NO_ERROR 0L // dderror    
...
```

In `ErrorHelper.h` :

```
...
namespace ErrorCodes
{
    enum Error
    {
        NO_ERROR = 0,// Not an error
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Even if `#undef NO_ERROR` is written before the `namepsace`the conflict still appears.

#### How can it be possible to get rid of this macro conflicts?

Is it somehow possible to bypass macro like this?

```
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
...
(std::min)(a, b); // std::min used instead of evil macro
```

Error occures in every line with `ErrorCodes::Error::NO_ERROR;`:

```
Error   C2059   syntax error: '::'  

Error   C2589   'constant': illegal token on right side of '::'
```

This conflict occurs with Visual Studio Compiler but compiles on Linaro GCC Snapshot 6.2-2016.11.

Comment: Do not include winerror.h if you have own error codes?

Comment: `#undef` everything and always avoid macros for `min` and other similar macros.

Comment: @S.M., it is not in my competence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Macros are a blunt tool that do all their damage before the C++ compiler gets to work. That's why it's good to minimise their use.

Assuming you don't want to suffer the renaming of your `enum`, value, you could always `#undef NO_ERROR` prior to your `enum` and in all places you use it.

With some toolsets supporting `push` and `pop` `pragma`s, this idea isn't too far-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

As Bathsheba mentioned already, you could `#undef` the pre-defined macro, however, I'd prefer not to do so; in general: especially if the values are not the same.

Still, you have another problem (which causes your compilation to fail even with the `#undef`): The scope of (classic) enum constants is not the enum, but its surrounding scope! So instead of `ErrorCodes::Error::NO_ERROR`, you need to refer to your enum values via `ErrorCodes::NO_ERROR`.

If you want to have scoped enums (since C++11), you need:

```
namespace ErrorCodes
{
    enum class Error
    //   ^^^^^
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Comment: I have tried already using `enum class Error`, and changing `ErrorCodes::Error::NO_ERROR` to `ErrorCodes::NO_ERROR` in different variants, but it didn't solve the conflict.

Comment: Then it possibly got re-defined somewhere. This might be the case if another header included winerror.h (directly or indirectly) after your header. Try including winerror.h yourself right before the undef. Further includes of winerror.h then should be neutral due to the include guards.